# D3.js: Multiple line charts mouseover with same x (time) showing different y (price)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to combine two D3.js examples I found 
here bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1157787 (multiples example)
and here bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569 (mouseover example).

So far everything works as intended. The mouseover focus is linked over all charts via x (time) displaying price values on every single chart at the same time. However the value and position displayed is set by the last chart's data showing wrong positions and values on all other charts. What I am trying to figure out is how to address every single chart with it's own values and focus positions. I found several similar questions concerning multiple charts and multiple mouseover focus positions, but not the two topics combined. I am new to JS and D3 so I don't know how to assign the right values to the right focus object. See here http://plnkr.co/edit/btAPsU0ra6uR3f4ZXZWj.
Here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  //shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.area {
  //fill: #e7e7e7;
  fill: transparent;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 8, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 138 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)         // x is the d3.time.scale()
  .orient("bottom") // the ticks go below the graph
  .ticks(4);        // specify the number of ticks

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(4);

d3.csv("stocks_chart2.csv", type, function(error, data) {

    // Nest data by symbol.
    var symbols = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.symbol; })
      .entries(data);

    // Compute the maximum price per symbol, needed for the y-domain.
    symbols.forEach(function(s) {
    s.maxPrice = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.price; });
    });

    // Compute the minimum and maximum date across symbols.
    // We assume values are sorted by date.
    x.domain([
    d3.min(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[0].date; }),
    d3.max(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[s.values.length - 1].date; })
    ]);

    // Add an SVG element for each symbol, with the desired dimensions and margin.
    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
      .data(symbols)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add the area path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]); return area(d.values); });

    // Add the line path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]); return line(d.values); });

    // Add a small label for the symbol name.
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 6)
      .attr("y", height - 6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

    svg.append('g')            // create a <g> element
      .attr('class', 'x axis') // specify classes
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") 
      .call(xAxis);            // let the axis do its thing

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value");

    var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

    focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.price) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.price));
  }

});

function type(d) {
  d.price = +d.price;
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  return d;
}

</script>
```

and the data.csv as used in the multiples example (shortened)

```
symbol,date,price
S&P 500,Jan 2000,1394.46
S&P 500,Feb 2000,1366.42
S&P 500,Mar 2000,1498.58
S&P 500,Apr 2000,1452.43
S&P 500,May 2000,1420.6
S&P 500,Jun 2000,1454.6
S&P 500,Jul 2000,1430.83
S&P 500,Aug 2000,1517.68
S&P 500,Sep 2000,1436.51
S&P 500,Oct 2000,1429.4
S&P 500,Nov 2000,1314.95
S&P 500,Dec 2000,1320.28
S&P 500,Jan 2001,1366.01
S&P 500,Feb 2001,1239.94
S&P 500,Mar 2001,1160.33
S&P 500,Apr 2001,1249.46
S&P 500,May 2001,1255.82
S&P 500,Jun 2001,1224.38
S&P 500,Jul 2001,1211.23
S&P 500,Aug 2001,1133.58
S&P 500,Sep 2001,1040.94
S&P 500,Oct 2001,1059.78
S&P 500,Nov 2001,1139.45
S&P 500,Dec 2001,1148.08
S&P 500,Jan 2002,1130.2
S&P 500,Feb 2002,1106.73
S&P 500,Mar 2002,1147.39
S&P 500,Apr 2002,1076.92
S&P 500,May 2002,1067.14
S&P 500,Jun 2002,989.82
S&P 500,Jul 2002,911.62
S&P 500,Aug 2002,916.07
S&P 500,Dec 2008,903.25
S&P 500,Jan 2009,825.88
S&P 500,Feb 2009,735.09
S&P 500,Mar 2009,797.87
S&P 500,Apr 2009,872.81
S&P 500,May 2009,919.14
S&P 500,Jun 2009,919.32
S&P 500,Jul 2009,987.48
S&P 500,Aug 2009,1020.62
S&P 500,Sep 2009,1057.08
S&P 500,Oct 2009,1036.19
S&P 500,Nov 2009,1095.63
S&P 500,Dec 2009,1115.1
S&P 500,Jan 2010,1073.87
S&P 500,Feb 2010,1104.49
S&P 500,Mar 2010,1140.45
MSFT,Jan 2000,39.81
MSFT,Feb 2000,36.35
MSFT,Mar 2000,43.22
MSFT,Apr 2000,28.37
MSFT,May 2000,25.45
MSFT,Jun 2000,32.54
MSFT,Jul 2000,28.4
MSFT,Aug 2000,28.4
MSFT,Sep 2000,24.53
MSFT,Oct 2000,28.02
MSFT,Nov 2000,23.34
MSFT,Dec 2000,17.65
MSFT,Jan 2001,24.84
MSFT,Feb 2001,24
MSFT,Mar 2001,22.25
MSFT,Apr 2001,27.56
MSFT,Aug 2009,24.43
MSFT,Sep 2009,25.49
MSFT,Oct 2009,27.48
MSFT,Nov 2009,29.27
MSFT,Dec 2009,30.34
MSFT,Jan 2010,28.05
MSFT,Feb 2010,28.67
MSFT,Mar 2010,28.8
AMZN,Jan 2000,64.56
AMZN,Feb 2000,68.87
AMZN,Mar 2000,67
AMZN,Apr 2000,55.19
AMZN,May 2000,48.31
AMZN,Jun 2000,36.31
AMZN,Jul 2000,30.12
AMZN,Aug 2000,41.5
AMZN,Sep 2000,38.44
AMZN,Oct 2000,36.62
AMZN,Nov 2000,24.69
AMZN,Dec 2000,15.56
AMZN,Jan 2001,17.31
AMZN,Feb 2001,10.19
AMZN,Mar 2001,10.23
AMZN,Apr 2001,15.78
AMZN,May 2001,16.69
AMZN,Jun 2001,14.15
AMZN,Jul 2001,12.49
AMZN,May 2007,69.14
AMZN,Jun 2007,68.41
AMZN,Jul 2007,78.54
AMZN,Aug 2007,79.91
AMZN,Sep 2007,93.15
AMZN,Oct 2007,89.15
AMZN,Nov 2007,90.56
AMZN,Dec 2007,92.64
AMZN,Jan 2008,77.7
AMZN,Feb 2008,64.47
AMZN,Mar 2008,71.3
AMZN,Apr 2008,78.63
AMZN,May 2008,81.62
AMZN,Jun 2008,73.33
AMZN,Jul 2008,76.34
AMZN,Aug 2008,80.81
AMZN,Sep 2008,72.76
AMZN,Oct 2008,57.24
AMZN,Nov 2008,42.7
AMZN,Dec 2008,51.28
AMZN,Jan 2009,58.82
AMZN,Feb 2009,64.79
AMZN,Mar 2009,73.44
AMZN,Apr 2009,80.52
AMZN,May 2009,77.99
AMZN,Jun 2009,83.66
AMZN,Jul 2009,85.76
AMZN,Aug 2009,81.19
AMZN,Sep 2009,93.36
AMZN,Oct 2009,118.81
AMZN,Nov 2009,135.91
AMZN,Dec 2009,134.52
AMZN,Jan 2010,125.41
AMZN,Feb 2010,118.4
AMZN,Mar 2010,128.82
IBM,Jan 2000,100.52
IBM,Feb 2000,92.11
IBM,Mar 2000,106.11
IBM,Jun 2003,75.42
IBM,Jul 2003,74.28
IBM,Aug 2003,75.12
IBM,Sep 2003,80.91
IBM,Mar 2009,95.09
IBM,Apr 2009,101.29
IBM,May 2009,104.85
IBM,Jun 2009,103.01
IBM,Jul 2009,116.34
IBM,Aug 2009,117
IBM,Sep 2009,118.55
IBM,Oct 2009,119.54
IBM,Nov 2009,125.79
IBM,Dec 2009,130.32
IBM,Jan 2010,121.85
IBM,Feb 2010,127.16
IBM,Mar 2010,125.55
GOOG,Aug 2004,102.37
GOOG,Sep 2004,129.6
GOOG,Oct 2004,190.64
GOOG,Nov 2004,181.98
GOOG,Dec 2004,192.79
GOOG,Jan 2005,195.62
GOOG,Feb 2005,187.99
GOOG,Mar 2005,180.51
GOOG,Apr 2005,220
GOOG,May 2005,277.27
GOOG,Jun 2005,294.15
GOOG,Jul 2005,287.76
GOOG,Aug 2005,286
GOOG,Sep 2005,316.46
GOOG,Oct 2005,372.14
GOOG,Nov 2005,404.91
GOOG,Dec 2005,414.86
GOOG,Jan 2006,432.66
GOOG,Feb 2006,362.62
GOOG,Mar 2006,390
GOOG,Apr 2006,417.94
GOOG,May 2006,371.82
GOOG,Jun 2006,419.33
GOOG,Jul 2006,386.6
GOOG,Aug 2006,378.53
GOOG,Sep 2006,401.9
GOOG,Oct 2006,476.39
GOOG,Nov 2006,484.81
GOOG,Jul 2009,443.05
GOOG,Aug 2009,461.67
GOOG,Sep 2009,495.85
GOOG,Oct 2009,536.12
GOOG,Nov 2009,583
GOOG,Dec 2009,619.98
GOOG,Jan 2010,529.94
GOOG,Feb 2010,526.8
GOOG,Mar 2010,560.19
10 Year T-Note,Jan 2000,6.67
10 Year T-Note,Feb 2000,6.41
10 Year T-Note,Mar 2000,6.02
10 Year T-Note,Apr 2000,6.21
10 Year T-Note,May 2000,6.28
10 Year T-Note,Jun 2000,6.02
10 Year T-Note,Jul 2000,6.03
10 Year T-Note,Aug 2000,5.73
10 Year T-Note,Sep 2000,5.78
10 Year T-Note,Oct 2000,5.76
10 Year T-Note,Nov 2000,5.44
10 Year T-Note,Dec 2000,5.11
10 Year T-Note,Jan 2001,5.18
10 Year T-Note,Feb 2001,4.91
10 Year T-Note,Mar 2001,4.91
10 Year T-Note,Apr 2001,5.34
10 Year T-Note,May 2001,5.41
10 Year T-Note,Jun 2001,5.39
10 Year T-Note,Jul 2001,5.04
10 Year T-Note,Aug 2001,4.82
10 Year T-Note,Sep 2001,4.57
AAPL,Jan 2000,25.94
AAPL,Feb 2000,28.66
AAPL,Mar 2000,33.95
AAPL,Apr 2000,31.01
AAPL,May 2000,21
AAPL,Jun 2000,26.19
AAPL,Jul 2000,25.41
AAPL,Aug 2000,30.47
AAPL,Sep 2000,12.88
AAPL,Oct 2000,9.78
AAPL,Nov 2000,8.25
AAPL,Dec 2000,7.44
AAPL,Jan 2001,10.81
AAPL,Feb 2001,9.12
AAPL,Mar 2001,11.03
AAPL,Apr 2001,12.74
AAPL,May 2001,9.98
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not quite got this working perfectly, but I believe this should get you started. The reason that what you're doing isn't working is because you're sharing the piece of data `d` across all of the charts.

```
function mousemove() {
    var date = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        index = bisectDate(data, date, 1),
        d0 = data[index - 1],
        d1 = data[index],
        d = date - d0.date > d1.date - date ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.price) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.price));
```

So this bit of code here is selecting all of the `focus` items that you're using for your tooltips, but is applying the formatted currency for `d.price`. However if you look at this, `d` that is driving the price is coming directly from the data from the mouse move.

Instead what you need to do is assign the data for each of the focus items individually. I've not quite got this fully working unfortunately as I've not tracked down how `index` is calculated but this gives the idea:

```
function mousemove() {
   var date = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
    index = bisectDate(data, date, 1),
    d0 = data[index - 1],
    d1 = data[index],
    d = date - d0.date > d1.date - date ? d1 : d0;

    var focus = svg.selectAll(".focus");

    focus.attr("translate", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.values[index].date) + "," + y(d.values[index].price) + ")"
    });

    focus.selectAll("text", function(d) {
      return formatCurrency(d.values[index].price);
    });
}
```

So what's going on here is that each of the `focus` items has their translation and text set specifically from the data that is driving that series. The `d` parameter is now being scoped (and will be provided automatically from D3 after it's previous data binding) to these functions and will be used to access the actual data that you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am making progress. I seem to be collecting the right values (see console.log below). However the transform/translate function of the focus attribute as well as it's text attribute seem to be broken although the values seem to be ok. Any hints? See http://plnkr.co/edit/u6OsFvnDDt4jwljyVyr5?p=preview. Thank you!

Comment: @Kai You're index isn't correct. It's showing the wrong values for me (and also only seems to be part way through the data-set when I'm at the far right of the graphs.

Comment: You are right, that is the problem I was talking about. When I comment out line 163: return "translate [...] index and values as seen by console.log are alright (see http://plnkr.co/edit/u6OsFvnDDt4jwljyVyr5?p=preview). There is something going on with the return "translate [...]" I can't quite figure out

Comment: Actually the mouseover works ok, it's the chart line that is not displaying the values correctly in some of the charts